# Delete nested table using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have here table showing records from database and a delete animation using jquery. I have also a Nested table. When I delete record the `<tr class="record">` in`<table id="tfhover">` is erased. I want to erased also the `<tr class="record">` in `<table id="loginTable'>` which is the nested table. Help please?

```
<table id="tfhover">
<thead>
        <tr>
        <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr class="record">
    <td><a href="#" name="'.$row["counter"].'" class="delbutton"><img src="images/del.png"></a></td>

<!-- NESTED TABLE-->

    <tr id="trow'.$rowid.'" style="display:none;"><td colspan=12 class="nested">
    <table id="loginTable'.$rowid.'">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr class="record"> //delete this row
        <td></td> //delete this row
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        </td></tr></tr>
        </tbody></table>
```

Script

```
<script>
$(function() {
$(".delbutton").click(function(){
//Save the link in a variable called element
var element = $(this);
//Find the id of the link that was clicked
var del_id = element.attr("name");
//Built a url to send
var info = 'name=' + del_id;

 if(confirm("Sure you want to delete this update? There is NO undo!"))
          {
 $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "delete.php",
   data: info,
   success: function(){
   }
 });
         $(this).parents(".record").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
        .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
 }
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove both `<tr class="record">`, just change

> $(this).parents(".record").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" },
>   "fast")
>           .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");

to

> $(".record").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
>           .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");

just like http://jsfiddle.net/6sDjP/

Comment: of course it delete all row, because you dont have more information in the table (at least in the table you post), check now http://jsfiddle.net/6sDjP/1/

Comment: The problem is all of my records in the database erased. I need to delete only the table row that I clicked

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like $(".record").remove(); with your html. Your html is malformed however. "" may not hurt but sure could. Also, the row containing "" is not closed.

You can not put anything between cell end and adjoining row end, which what I think you have done.

Comment: remove? I just want to erased only the table row that I clicked